# What is the default behaviour of IPv4LL on Linuxsystems?

Tags: linux, ip, dhcp

I'm looking for a good source and confirmation about **Dynamic Configuration of IPv4 Link-Local Addresses.**

The rfc [Dynamic Configuration of IPv4 Link-Local Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927) didn't really help answer my question (or I'm looking over it).

*So let's review, to make sure I am right:*

When a device connects to the internet, and it doesn't get an IP from either DHCP or static. Then the device receives an IP in the 169.254/16 range. This process is called *APIPA* (=Automatic Private IP Addressing) on Microsoft Operating systems and is the default course of actions. A Linux variant is seemingly zeroconf/Avahi.

*My Question:*

Is the receiving of the IP in the range a default behaviour on any system (so on any Linux system). Or is/should it be configured by the OS. As far as I know when booting on Ubuntu and not doing "anything" will result in not getting an IP whatsoever (so no 169.254.x.y/16).

In other words when we speak of not getting a IP from DHCP (and not statically setting one). Will/should I receive a 169.245/16 IP on every system or is this Microsoft-only stuff?

EDIT: also what does OSX do?

Comment: It depends on your configuration but why would you need a 169 address if the link is not operational?  You just leave the interface down.  It won't be routable either way.